# Why does IE7 when clearing a float result in a margin bug?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have a very simple HTML page (validates as XHTML 1.0 Strict):

```
<div class="news-result">
    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2><span class="date">(1-1-2009)</span>
    <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.news-result {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0 20px;
}

.news-result h2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.news-result span.date {
    margin: 1px 0 0;
    float : left;
}

.news-result p {
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
    clear: left;
}
```

Rendering this page in IE6 or FF3 render perfectly (the title and the date on a single line, followed by the paragraph). In IE7 however, there is a large space between the title and date, and the paragraph.

We have a simple reset that clears every margin and padding on every element.

Dropping the float on the date element fixes this problem, as does setting `zoom: 1` on the paragraph or removing `overflow: hidden` on the container, but all are not ideal. Why does a float followed by a paragraph trigger this additional top margin, only on IE7?

Answer (score 4):

Can I assume that you have a doc-type?

However, change the h2 and span to display: inline; should also clear up your issue.

Edit --- adding hasLayout

Understanding that inline isn't always an option, here's an [article explaining what's going on](http://www.search-this.com/2007/09/05/lets-be-clear-about-this/).

Essentially you have to give the `<p>` hasLayout. There are many ways to do this, and I don't like using `<div class="clearall"></div>` and prefer to use `overflow: hidden;` or `zoom: 1;`

Comment: Our doctype is XHTML 1.0 Strict (and validates @ W3C).

Comment: Display: inline does clear it up, but does not allow us to have a float before the `p`, something we need in some situations.

Comment: Edited to add the explanation / solution link

Comment: One more thing to note - it's the 30px padding on .news-result that IE7's duplicating, so if you find another way to add padding (a second div?), you'll be good on this too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the extra whitespace in IE6, 7 and 8B2.

It appears that IE has a non-zero top-margin applied to the `<p>` tag.

I was able to remove the whitespace in IE by making the following change:

```
.news-result p {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
    clear: left;
}
```

The change did not seem to have any negative side-effects in Firefox 2 or 3, Opera 9.63 or Safari for Windows 3.2.1.

Comment: Utilizing a css reset ala Eric Meyer: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/ will help minimize some of the browser differences you may be experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `&nbsp;` between the floated DIV and the clearing div. That will remove the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Because IE7 is [**still**](http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/11/11/ie-7-quirks-floats-and-margins/) [float](http://retiredblog.gkaindl.com/2007/05/07/ie7-floatmargin-bottom-annoyance/) [bugged](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html), I'm afraid.

*(fixes at the links)*

Comment: It is the margin top that appears unwanted, and not a margin bottom that does not appear.